# UICollectionView gets really slow when using sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with images separated by categories. Each category is a section, so I enabled `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` to pin the category name to the top of the view.

It works fine, only problem is, scrolling became *really* slow. I was able to improve it a little bit by using `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`, but on an iPad for example, it's still slow.

And it's not even related to the images. On the iPad Air, where the issue is even worse, even if I load a bunch of empty cells, scrolling is still slow!

For example:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mycell", for: indexPath)
cell.backgroundColor = .blue
return cell
```

Only way to get smooth scrolling again is disabling `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds`